# Post-upgrade issue: blockheight stuck at 1546200

Tags: blockchain-size

So I've been follwing the official upgrade guide (posted here and on getmonero.org.)

I have updated my binaries, PGP-verified them. Now my issue is that when I have a `monero-wallet-cli` session open, when I run `bc_height`, I keep on getting 1546200, and it never changes over time. I made sure `monerod` is running in the background.

What could be the source of this issue, and how may I fix it?

*EDIT:*

I have looked into the `monerod` log. Looks like it's looping over the same block over and over again ("`Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546107`")
Maybe this can be a hint into where the problem lies?

Note how the blockheight 1546200 keeps on being repeated throughout the log.

```
:18.702 [P2P3]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [172.87.222.52:63617 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546545 [Your node is 345 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-04-07 10:55:40.008 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [86.238.48.197:55908 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546107 [Your node is 93 blocks (0 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-04-07 10:56:01.093 [P2P1]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [115.70.158.104:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546107 [Your node is 93 blocks (0 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-04-07 10:56:05.234 [P2P4]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [5.79.127.3:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546107 [Your node is 93 blocks (0 days) ahead] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-04-07 11:00:06.245 [P2P8]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [24.72.65.53:45675 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546601 [Your node is 401 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
2018-04-07 11:00:12.806 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1475 ----- BLOCK ADDED AS ALTERNATIVE ON HEIGHT 1546105
id: <839313dfb9ac548b96dcaef2df6b61805266f1a13334694e0683784e076f7afa>
PoW:    <b3acabff4c6b129a9830433e7b2647d498923b714e2b7879d21b3f0400000000>
difficulty: 99825426467
2018-04-07 11:00:13.327 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1475 ----- BLOCK ADDED AS ALTERNATIVE ON HEIGHT 1546106
id: <6c87e1d81a0d95dba7d80374fe32091072f2ecdc8dca11801d0c6a34d16fad53>
PoW:    <3e82477e9f7a3304b9c217d238a41a23ef298f9c6506a596b127e80600000000>
difficulty: 99179807859
2018-04-07 11:00:13.796 [P2P9]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1475 ----- BLOCK ADDED AS ALTERNATIVE ON HEIGHT 1546107
id: <b6f88631f7afdcdbe69e7d49e6e2a5726e7973ab85ae020e5619afb8227265c3>
PoW:    <eb6e6dd5b15fe5fa18b923ef7e27dedd0c911882aa32702a04c0ad0000000000>
difficulty: 98591306489
2018-04-07 11:01:56.189 [P2P0]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:310 [83.162.43.154:61616 INC] Sync data returned a new top block candidate: 1546200 -> 1546585 [Your node is 385 blocks (0 days) behind] 
SYNCHRONIZATION started
```

TIA!

Comment: Were you running v.0.11 monerod past block 1546000?  And then you got the new binaries?  You can see that your block height is past the actual chain height.  You may need to do `monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 250` to get your chain to before the fork height, so it can choose the right chain when it gets to 1546000.

Comment: Use this guide to resolve your issue: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result