# I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and, as a result, accidentally synced to the wrong (alternative) chain

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, monerod, synchronization, blockchain-import

I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and, as a result, accidentally synced to the wrong (alternative) chain. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the most recent version, this particular issue is, fortunately, trivially fixed as follows:

**GUI**

1. Exit the GUI by clicking on the `x` (right top) and subsequently making sure to stop the daemon as well.
2. Upgrade to GUI v0.14.0.0 -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/ayshug/gui_v01400_boron_butterfly_released/
3. Start the "new" GUI (v0.14.0.0) and let it start the daemon.
4. The GUI (v0.14.0.0) should now automatically resolve your issue + perform a database conversion. However, this may take quite some time. Therefore, I'd advise to let it run overnight. Note that the GUI may state that it cannot connect to the daemon. You can safely ignore this message though and let the GUI run.
5. If you also made a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain, proceed with this guide:

[I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and created / performed a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-13-to-cli-or-gui-v0-14-and-created-pe)

---

**CLI**

1. Exit all Monero related processes by simply typing `exit`
2. Upgrade to CLI v0.14.0.2 -> https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.14.0.2
3. Start the "new" v0.14.0.2 `monerod`
4. The daemon (monerod - v0.14.0.2) should now automatically resolve your issue. However, this may take quite some time. Therefore, I'd advise to let it run overnight.
5. If you also made a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain, proceed with this guide:

[I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.13 to CLI or GUI v0.14) and created / performed a transaction on the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7993/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-13-to-cli-or-gui-v0-14-and-created-pe)

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please explain step 4 for Windows? it doesn't make sense. The "new" directory and the "GUI v0.12.0.0" directory are the same

Comment: @gamliela - There is a more trivial way to resolve this particular issue, i.e., simply upgrade to GUI v0.12.2.0 -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8vkx2g/gui_v01220_released/. The GUI v0.12.2.0 should now automatically resolve your issue. However, this may take quite some time. Therefore, I'd advise to let it run overnight. Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. I actually came to this issue after my wallet synced to the wrong chain (cause I did the upgrade after April). Will this new version get synced to the "real" chain automatically?

Comment: @gamliela - I've also updated the answer to reflect the more trivial instructions.