# blockheight unconfirmed

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, blockchain, synchronization, block-height

I'm using the new GUI and made a deposit on it from an exchange.
32 hours ago it was approved from the exchange. Since then i'm waiting to see the amount on my wallet. I can see it in the history, but it says: Blockheight unconfirmed and the balance hasn't changed until now. 
Deamon says its sync, but stands on the same blocksize 1546572 since 2 days.
When i look it up with mxrchain it says it was tranfsered on block 1546105.
I also deleted the cache and synced again.
What can i do about it?

Comment: From which exchange did you withdraw?

Comment: bitfinex, but it was approved ~34 hours ago and 12 hours later it appeared in the monero gui history. But still unconfirmed and the block size is stuck. link from xmrcain: https://xmrchain.net/search?value=839313dfb9ac548b96dcaef2df6b61805266f1a13334694e0683784e076f7afa+

Comment: Is your transaction included in that block? Because you linked a block hash, not a transaction hash. Also, could you go to the `Settings` page and press `Show status`. Subsequently, paste the output here.

Comment: yes, it was included in this block. status was always at 100%. It was probably a problem with the local configs which also explains the stuck sync at 1546572 since 1 day. i renamed 4 times the files with no .ending and synced again with no improvement. Also pop-blocks back some days. then i switched the local node to remote node and renamed again. now the correct amount is in the gui, also after switching back to local again. thank you for your assistence! Now i can look forward to the upcoming Airdrop V.

Comment: You're welcome and good to hear you resolved your issue. Btw, if you still want to run your own node, use this guide first to pop blocks: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result

Comment: aaand it's still the problem with local node. i made the pop-block 8000 and the rename of the file, with no improvement. still blocksize 1546572. do i realy need to delete the data.mdb and p2pstate as last try? seems that the data is about 50gb big and it will take me days to sync the blocks till now. last row of the power shell stands on fpr hours. Is this the finished message i should wait for? Or could it take more hours to finish? last message: 2018-04-13 13:47:58.226 1580 INFO bcutil src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp:758 height: 1546572

Comment: You need to pop blocks such that the process ends before block `1546000`. As you can see, your process ended at -> `INFO bcutil src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp:758 height: 1546572` or block `1546572`. Therefore, I'd advise to rerun `monero-blockchain-import`. If it does not run properly with `--pop-blocks 8000`, try running `--pop 1000` eight times.