# monerod block height is 1,500,000 - How do i pop off 100,000 blocks and start syncing at 1,400,000 instead?

Tags: monerod, synchronization, monerod-commands

What is the monerod command to pop off a certain amount of blocks? Say I am at block 1.5 million and I want to start from 1.4 million instead. What is the monerod command for this?

Comment: monero-wallet-cli  --restore-height 1400000

Comment: that doesnt work. its something to do with block popping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are searching for on linux called:

> ./monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 100000

and on windows you need to use

> monero-blockchain-import.exe --pop-blocks 100000

A detailed howto is on point 4 at [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result/) answer from dEBRUYNE.