# Transaction from GUI wallet to bittrex account never arrived. PLEASE HELP

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-confirmation, exchange

On April 11th 22:37 a friend of mine transferred 78.0 XMR from his GUI wallet v.11 to my Bittrex account.

in his GUI wallet on the history page it shows successful transaction and 78 xmr haven been deducted from main balance on GUI. In GUI under check payment it shows transaction successful with more than 10k confirmations. 
Now, on April 26th I still don’t have received the 78 XMR on bittrex.
I can not find the transaction on the blockchain either (using tx ID or payment ID)
All addresses are 100 percent correct as I double and triple checked everything.
I have now updated the GUI to v12 and changed the wallet file name which caused the GUI to resync but the balance still shows zero.
If its not on the wallet and not in the blockchain, then where can it be?
I have made several transactions before with this wallet and everything always was fine.

Can you please help me, I don’t know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Monero had a hard fork on the 6th you sent a transaction on the 11th after the hardfork had occurred. You have sent Monero Original to your Bittrex account and not Monero. Try using [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result) guide to re-sync to the correct chain with your old balance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t follow the above instructions do this.

Wipe out your complete installation of the Monero software.  Download a new copy of the GUI, restore your wallet from your seed phrase, and download a complete, start from scatch, block 0, copy of the block chain. All your coins in your wallet will then appear and you will be up to date on everything.