# Wrong chain, maybe - maybe not - no transaction possible, wrong balance... please help!

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm really getting so frustrated - cannot resolve following issue:

- My wallet is showing the wrong balance
- I cannot transfer any money ("Daemon is busy")

Seems like I am on the wrong chain, right?

So I tried following this guideline:

[I forgot to upgrade (from CLI or GUI v0.11 to CLI or GUI v0.12) and, as a result, accidentally synced to the wrong (alternative) chain](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7989/i-forgot-to-upgrade-from-cli-or-gui-v0-11-to-cli-or-gui-v0-12-and-as-a-result/)

I updated from 12.2 to 12.3 and now I've been waiting for days and theres nothing happening. I am on Macosx High Sierra using the GUI version.

This is what my log says:

`[31.07.18 09:01] Height: 1622140/1622140 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 458.90 MH/s, v7, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 8h 1m 44s
[31.07.18 09:02] Height: 1622140/1622140 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 458.90 MH/s, v7, up to date, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 8h 2m 44s`

The latest transaction to this wallet happened in block no "1615882" with now "No of confirmations: 12630" - these funds are not showing in my wallet and I cannot transfer the existing funds...

I do not want to delete the whole blockchain and start over from scratch...

Do you have any tips? I really do need the money :( - Thank u

Comment: Do you vaguely remember when you first made a transaction to this particular wallet? Btw, your `Show status` output looks OK (i.e. you are on the correct chain).

Comment: thank you for your reply! ah okay, so I am on the right chain - then that's even more confusing. The first transaction was in block height 1581264, I reduced my wallet creation height to claim my funds.

Comment: So a second transaction is missing? What is the output of this guide (for the transaction that is missing)? https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6137/how-do-i-as-a-recipient-verify-that-my-transaction-actually-arrived

Comment: Okay no, the first transactions are all fine and showing up. There seems to be a problem only with the last one (Block height 1615882 as mentioned above). The test gives me "This address owns output 0 with pubkey XXX for amount XXX"  Next line "This address doesn't own output with pubkey XXX for amount XXX" and total received: XXX, indicating the correct amount of XMR -  so from here everything looks fine

Comment: Okay now not using GUI: I popped the blocks as described below, resynced for ages - now I have my funds in the wallet-cli! GUI version still not showing right funds although "fully synced" --- that thing is a mess!

Comment: Good to hear your funds are showing in the CLI. With respect to the GUI, can you try the following steps: 1. Exit `monero-wallet-cli` by typing `exit` | 2. Go to the `Settings` page of the GUI and press `Close wallet` | 3. On the second page of the wizard (first page is language selection) choose `Open a wallet from file` | 4. Now select the `.keys` file of the wallet you used in the CLI. Do you properly see your balance in the GUI now too?

Comment: Really, thank you so much for your patience and for your reply! I think I will stick to the command line from now on - - I will try your tip later

Comment: Did you solve your problem after all?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to rescan your wallet for spent output with `rescan_spent` from the cli. It should remove your spent transaction done on the wrong blockchain.

Otherwise you could try to pop the blocks to restart syncing before the transaction:
`./monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 6500`
This will remove the 6500 blocks and when you will restart monerod it will sync again.

Edit: try first option. If it does not help, pop the blocks and scan again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Option 1 did not have any effect (no wonder, since it seems that I am indeed on the right chain).. so I'm trying option two now...